# is there a way to delay `systemctl reboot` using only `systemctl`?

Tags: shutdown, reboot, systemctl, delay

I understand that there is a multitude of options to shutdown or reboot a linux system. Normally I would just use `shutdown` with the appropriate option.

However, I find myself having no control of the environment and needing to reboot the system using only `systemctl` but having to do so with a delay. Now `systemctl` supports `poweroff` und `reboot` which however in turn do not support delays afaik and as far as `man` is concerned.

Is there a way to delay a `systemctl reboot` for `x` seconds without resorting to other commands like `sleep 3 && systemctl reboot` but just using `systemctl`?

I could not find anything regarding a `systemctl shutdown` command, but understand that e.g. `reboot` invokes the shutdown (systemcall|command).
`man` for `systemctl`, `reboot`, `systemd-halt.service` didn't list any delay parameter/configuration options.

[original question was posed on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/okmihi/systemctl_poweroff_with_delay/), but I it fit here better.

Comment: i suppose "at" command is out of question

Comment: sadly yes in this case

Comment: Do you need to do this literally using the `systemctl` command? or just via systemd somehow? If the latter, there is `systemd-run` for scheduling jobs using transient systemd timers.

Comment: interesting suggestion; gonna have to have a look; thanks; I'll report back if it works or not...